# Angular Material: How to make a custom form component with a inputContainer to be used in a reactive form?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular2-forms

I want to create custom form components that takes care of error messages itself.  These components use the angular material design, and will be used in a page that uses reactive forms.

I simplified my code to get rid of the noise.  This is just a simple example of what I want to accomplish.

MyForm.component.ts

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
      <app-text-input formControlName="myTextInput"></app-text-input>
    </form>
  `
})
export class MyForm implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = fb.group({myTextInput:['',Validators.required]});
  }
}
```

TextInput.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  template: `
    <div class="text-input">
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="value">
        <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
      </md-input-container>
   </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    provide:     NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(()=>TextInput),
    multi:       true,
  ]
})

export class TextInput implements ControlValueAccessor {

  _value: string;

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.propagateChange(val);
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    if (value) {
      this._value = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(): void {
  }

}
```

I tried several scenarios:

**A.** make TextInput a validator (implements Validator, provider: NG_VALIDATORS).  This way it's possible to know the error state of the TextInput component, based on the reactive form of the parent.  But I can't propagate this state to the input container in the text input itself.  How can I do that?

**B.** Copy/paste the validators of the TextInput component to the internal Input component.  I don't know how to do this correctly...

**C.** Mis-use mdHint with error-css to show errors based on the error-state that is grabbed when implementing scenario A.

Some tricks I used during my search:

Get the name of the form control element:

```
@Input()
formControlName: string;
```

Get the control container of TextInput in the constructor:

```
constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.control = this.controlContainer['form'].controls(this.formControlName);
}
```

Get the inputContainer containing the inner input element:

```
@ViewChild(MdInputContainer) inputContainer: MdInputContainer;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const innerControl = this.inputContainer._mdInputChild._ngControl;
  ...
}
```